# Can't update document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So i'm trying to simply update a document in my database, i had no issues with getting data from the database. Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

//Creating Schema
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [String],
  date: Date,
  name: String,
  author: String,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number,
});

//Creating model which returns a Class
const Course = mongoose.model("courses", courseSchema);


async function updateData(id) {
  try {
    const course = await Course.findById(id);

    course.isPublished = true;
    course.author = "another author";

    const resulti = await course.save();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
updateData("5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd");
```

Error i recieve:

```
Cannot set property 'isPublished' of null
```

Any pointers are appreciated thanks in advance:)

Comment: I think you should give the default value as 'false' to 'isPublished' field.

Comment: When finding course, the id cannot be found. So it returns null.

Comment: To clarify: When finding course, the document with id cannot be found. So it returns null. This is not an error and will not stop your function there. So it errors on setting a property on null.

Comment: Yea, makes sense. But how do i debug this tho. I can literally get the data from the database, with the exact same model, console.log that and copy one of the ID's from there. Still does not work.

Comment: I tried using updateOne instead and then i set the third parameter, upsert:true. So if it doesen't find the ID it should create it. And it did. So now i have two ID's who looks like this:
_    id:ObjectID("5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777")

    _id:"5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777"

So, now the code in this post works. However it updates the _id with the former formatting, which is not what i want as all my id:s are formated as the latter version

Comment: Alright i have found the solution, seems as i am following a course, the formatting of the downloaded database is deprecated, thanks for pointing me in the right direction:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the database i was using had deprecated formatting for the id:s.

```
//In my database
_id: "5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777"

//How it should look
_id: ObjectID("5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777")
```